# Missing Master Key Error Github Action with test.key stored as a secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-actions, credentials

I am going crazy with Rails Credentials!
I have a `Missing Master Key Error` when launching my Github Action test.

I have

1. generated `credentials/test.key` and `credentials/test.yml.enc` with `rails credential:edit -e test` command,
2. stored the content of `test.key` in a GITHUB Actions Secret
3. referenced it in my Github Action

   ```
   env:
     RAILS_ENV: test      
     RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
   ```

Still say "Missing Key"...
I also have done the same in production (as before the master.key was stored on Github!!)

EDIT: solved! there are 2 options on working with Credentials. One `maskter.key` for all environments or a production.key / development.key.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following to add the key under `config` before you start running the tests.

`echo "$RAILS_MASTER_KEY" > config/master.key`

Comment: thanks, it did not work. I rolled back and step by step found a way. The lack of documentation and technical debt made it hard to understand where was the real encryption key